# Should we check for a character in a string before applying delete!()?

Tags: ruby

This is fairly trivial but has bugged me for quite a while.

I have a string:

```
x = 'abc/'
```

And want to remove the '/' token.

The simplest way I know to do it is:

```
x.delete!('/')
```

which works fine. Checking the object ID:

```
x = 'abc/'
x.object_id     # => 90851540
x.delete!('/')
x.object_id     # => 90851540
x               # => "abc"
```

The object id stayed the same, so I conclude that 
Ruby modified  `x` as-is, without generating a new copy.

Is it better to check whether the string actually has a '/' character in the first place, before 
applying `delete!()` to it?

I remember that someone once said that "it does not matter"
since `delete!()` will check on the given String anyway,
and only make a modification if the String has the character.

That's fair enough.

But I am wondering about pros and cons of either
approach. Would:

```
if x.include? '/'
```

be faster? Would it be better or more convenient?

Within the code it may be clearer, but it
also makes the code somewhat more verbose and perhaps it
may also lead to some overhead.

Sometimes I use `delete!()` alone, without any check, and sometimes I do a check.

Is one way better than the 
other, because right now I am slightly in favour of 
"no if check", not because of speed reasons but largely
because of less syntax/less code.

Comment: Probably only if you care if the token is present or if you will use the return from the `delete!()` method.

Comment: Obligatory [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1691/)

Comment: This sounds like Yak shaving. You need to learn to use benchmarks for these questions. You can test and prove to yourself that way. Look at the "[Fruity](https://github.com/marcandre/fruity)" gem and the [Benchmark](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/index.html) class in the Standard Library. By reading existing code you'll find the idiomatic use of the methods and find that we don't bother looking if we're going to delete a character. If it exists deleting will find it and remove it. The action of looking prior only wastes CPU. `delete!` vs `delete` is programmer choice.

Comment: `str = 'cat'.delete('a') #=> 'ct'; str = 'cat'.delete!('r') #=> nil`, the latter because `'cat'` was not changed. You therefore need to check to see if `'cat'` contains an `'r'` if (and only if) you want to use the return value and expect it to be the possibly-modified string.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably go with `delete!` without checking most of the time ("less code" and still clear), but lets evaluate performance:

#### test.rb

```
require 'benchmark'

iterations = 1_000_000

puts "'/' ALWAYS PRESENT"
Benchmark.bmbm do |bm|
  bm.report('without if') do
    iterations.times do
      x = "abc/"
      x.delete!("/")
    end
  end

  bm.report('with if') do
    iterations.times do
      x = "abc/"
      x.delete!("/") if x.include?("/")
    end
  end
end

puts "\n'/' NEVER PRESENT"
Benchmark.bmbm do |bm|
  bm.report('without if') do
    iterations.times do
      x = "abc"
      x.delete!("/")
    end
  end

  bm.report('with if   ') do
    iterations.times do
      x = "abc"
      x.delete!("/") if x.include?("/")
    end
  end
end
```

#### Results

```
'/' ALWAYS PRESENT
Rehearsal ----------------------------------------------
without if   0.540000   0.000000   0.540000 (  0.541003)
with if      0.630000   0.010000   0.640000 (  0.632728)
------------------------------------- total: 1.180000sec

                 user     system      total        real
without if   0.510000   0.000000   0.510000 (  0.513438)
with if      0.630000   0.000000   0.630000 (  0.632055)

'/' NEVER PRESENT
Rehearsal ----------------------------------------------
without if   0.510000   0.000000   0.510000 (  0.513233)
with if      0.190000   0.000000   0.190000 (  0.194709)
------------------------------------- total: 0.700000sec

                 user     system      total        real
without if   0.510000   0.000000   0.510000 (  0.514632)
with if      0.180000   0.000000   0.180000 (  0.186374)
```

Based on this results, we see (as one may expect) that checking before deleting is a bit slower (due to that extra check) than just deleting without checking **when** the string contains `/`. However, when `/` is not present, then checking first is much faster.

So, from a performance point of view, you may want to use `include?` if you expect a high percentage of cases without `/`.

---

In case you're wondering what would it look like with a *50%/50%* scenario, here's the test:

#### test.rb

```
require 'benchmark'

iterations = 500_000

puts "\n'/' PRESENT IN 50%"
Benchmark.bmbm do |bm|
  bm.report('without if') do
    iterations.times do
      x = "abc/"
      x.delete!("/")
    end

    iterations.times do
      x = "abc"
      x.delete!("/")
    end
  end

  bm.report('with if   ') do
    iterations.times do
      x = "abc/"
      x.delete!("/") if x.include?("/")
    end

    iterations.times do
      x = "abc"
      x.delete!("/") if x.include?("/")
    end
  end
end
```

#### Results

```
'/' PRESENT IN 50%
Rehearsal ----------------------------------------------
without if   0.540000   0.010000   0.550000 (  0.554114)
with if      0.410000   0.000000   0.410000 (  0.419098)
------------------------------------- total: 0.960000sec

                 user     system      total        real
without if   0.540000   0.000000   0.540000 (  0.549411)
with if      0.410000   0.000000   0.410000 (  0.420603)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not check for the simple reason, it is redundant.
Even though I check for token existence, ruby is anyway going to check for it again (and no way to skip that).
One issue i see is nil check, the variable might be nil. In that case too, i would do something like `variable.to_s.delete!()`.
Thus, I think I have enough reasons to skip check/verify existence of token and no reason I think of for doing defensive coding.

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't sure that `x.to_s.delete!('/')` would modify `x` in place. It does.